# SUMIFS should consider both blank & not blank values.with single formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Sheet1]

Hello All,
Below is the situation where  Product Column is having 2 values:"A" & blank, where product is not know. I'm trying to calculate how total qty of Product A & unknown product.

I'm using SUMIFS condition, but formula doesn't consider blank cells (unknown product). How to consider blank cells, so that total qty would be "11" for unknown product.

Formula used
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,A:A)

[image: sheet3]
I a common formula that can be used through column D or E.

Comment: `=SUM(SUMIF(A1:A7,{"A",""},B1:B7))` and similar to sumifs

Comment: You can fill the blank cells with single quotation marks?

Comment: @TheGridLock Can we have one formula where column has not blank & blank sum if condition with not blank and blank criteria?

Comment: Can you upload an image that describes what you want?

Comment: @TheGridLock Uploaded image 3. Need a common formula that can be used through Column F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following formula solves your problem:

`=IF(ISBLANK(E2),SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,""),SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,E2))`

I reproduced it with your data and it returned 11 for the unknown products.

Answer (score 1):

This works well, please try it:

- `$D$1:$D$2&""` as i understand it will fill a `vbnullstring value` type instead of empty cell, and it is a condition for countif to count cells with `value = ""`

.

```
=SUMIF($A$1:$A$7,INDEX($D$1:$D$7&"",ROW(D1)),$B$1:$B$7)
```

[image]

Comment: Do not use B:B, but should set restrictions B1:B100 or .. otherwise the formula will run very slowly

Answer (score 0):

I went for summing for "A" and "<>A" ie not "A", like so:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but need a common formula where in column D or F.

Answer (score 0):

In "Criteria" column `D2` enter : "A" and `D3` enter : =""

then,

In "Total Qty" column `E2`, enter formula and copied down to `E3` :

```
=SUMIF(A:A,D2,B:B)
```

[image]